# Default Image for ImageField

Tags: python, django, django-models, static

Hi I'm trying to set up a default image for a ToDo List in Django. I have a the images under **static/images**.
Now I'm trying to add a function where you can add tasks. in thid function I can choose a image. If no image is chosen, the image will become a default image ex. Placeholder.png

I tried creating a if else loop in models.py but that does not work either. Showing chosen images does work.

**models.py:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    technologie = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        if self.image:
            return self.image.url
        else:
            return "static/images/Placeholder.png"
```

Now my question is how can I set Placeholder.png from the static directory as a default for ImageField?

Comment: Should probably have a leading slash `"/static/images/Placeholder.png"` (or it is a relative path from current path) or even better, use the template tag `static("images/Placeholder.png")`. That way, it will still work, if you ever change the `STATIC_URL` setting. Also, don't forget to `manage.py collectstatic` since the default image is a static resource where as the uploads are media.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that solution!

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thanks the leading slash thing worked! Maybe you wanna Post your Comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this as this work fine for me hope it would be help you as well :)

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',default="images/Placeholder.png")
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that solution!

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me but I was able to solve my question!